# Can't parse span id on beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to write a scraper but i have faced with an issue.
I can parse "class in spans" and "class in div" but when i try to parse "id in span" it doesn't print the data i want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://bscscan.com/token/0xc3d33bdd0b6cea10eb496fbc7592e45f2624c0a5', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')


name = soup.find('span', class_='text-secondary small').text
add = soup.find('div', class_='mr-3').text
trans = soup.find('span', attrs={'id':'totaltxns'}).text



print(name, add, trans)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pick up a session cookie then make a request to an additional endpoint. sid needs to be dynamically picked up as well.

```
import requests, re

def get_transfer_count(str:token)->str:
    
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
        r = s.get(f'https://bscscan.com/token/{token}')
        sid = re.search(r"var sid = '(.*?)'", r.text).group(1)
        r = s.get(f'https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=normal&contractAddress={token}&a=&sid={sid}&p=1')
        return re.search(r"var totaltxns = '(.*?)'", r.text).group(1)
    
token = '0x8df9655178350146eAD837B15ba3D32c9Fe1497d'

get_transfer_count(token)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but why can't i just parse it like other datas by using "soup.find" command?

Comment: The value is dynamically retrieved, via JavaScript, and loaded into the location you see on the initial webpage. `requests` won't run JavaScript so I searched for where it was retrieved from.